# Cocoa encryption plain text?

Tags: cocoa, file, encryption, aes

I'm working on an encryption application that for now encrypts text-only files. I need some help in the connections and how to go about the actual encryption. I received this snippet of code to encrypt a file, but I am a bit confused. What I need to do is have a button (encrypt) that takes this text file and encrypts it. Am I supposed to extract the contents of the file first, then encrypt it? How so? The program must know what file has been selected so it encrypts it, and I'm a complete noob right now, and I need some help.

Step by step instructions would be greatly appreciated.

This was the code:

```
- (NSData*) encryptString:(NSString*)plaintext withKey:(NSString*)key {
    return [[plaintext dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] AES256EncryptWithKey:key];
}
```

I've implemented a file chooser with the following snippet:

```
- (IBAction)fileChooser:(id)sender {
    int i;
    NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [openDlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];
    [openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
    [openDlg setPrompt:@"Select"];
    if ([openDlg runModalForDirectory:nil file:nil] == NSOKButton )
    {
        NSArray* files = [openDlg filenames];
        for( i = 0; i < [files count]; i++ )
        {
            [files objectAtIndex:i];

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You are on the right track. You have your file. Now what you need to to is pull out the text so that you can pass it into your encryptString method (look at NSString, I believe it is stringWithContentsOfFile). Once you encrypt the string, you will have an NSData instance. All you need to do is write a new file with that data (look in NSData, writeToFile). Hopefully someone will be kind of enough to leave a more detailed answer for you but that should get you going.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was wondering, how should i connect this NSString method to a button, but it doesn't work if i just like wrap an IBAction over it, again please ignore my ignorance. Thanks!

Comment: You should implement the action method in your class for a controller object that either loads the nib containing the window (and the button) or is in the same nib. In a non-document-based application, this object either is the application's delegate or is created by the object that is the application's delegate. I go the latter route, as it keeps my code better organized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This was the code:
>
> ```
> - (NSData*) encryptString:(NSString*)plaintext withKey:(NSString*)key {
>     return [[plaintext dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] AES256EncryptWithKey:key];
> }
> ```

First, look at the receiver of the `AES256EncryptWithKey:` message. This is another, nested message:

```
[plaintext dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

What's `plaintext`? It's declared there in your `encryptString:withKey:` method: It is a variable holding a pointer to an NSString.

So you're sending the `dataUsingEncoding:` message to an NSString instance.

That's good if you intend to encrypt some plain-text user input, but it's not so good for encrypting files. NSStrings are for nothing but human characters; the user will probably want to encrypt files that are not plain text, such as images and video files.

**I know you said that your application “for now encrypts text-only files”, but the solution is actually simpler when you throw out this restriction.**

So you need to encrypt any data, not just a string. Delete your `encryptString:withKey:` method—it is useless.

From the implementation of that late method, we know that you were sending `AES256EncryptWithKey:` to an object obtained by sending `dataUsingEncoding:` to an NSString instance.

If you look in [the documentation for NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/), you can see [what `dataUsingEncoding:` returns](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/dataUsingEncoding%3a). Spoiler: It returns an NSData object.

From there, it's one hyperlink away to [the NSData documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/), where you will find two things:

1. It has no method by the selector `AES256EncryptWithKey:`.
2. It does have methods to create a data object from the contents of a file. (I'll let you find them.)

I'm assuming that you knew #1, and downloaded a category implementation from somewhere. I'm also assuming that, in fact, this category *is* on NSData; the category's `@interface`, in its header, will tell you.

In Objective-C, you should not use an index loop to iterate through an array unless you actually need the index for something, which you generally don't and you, specifically, don't. Instead, use [fast enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html):

```
for (NSString *path in [openPanel filenames]) {
}
```

You can see how, again, this makes the solution simpler. It's also faster.

Inside that loop, pass that path to the NSData class method that creates an NSData object from the contents of a file. Then, send that data object the `AES256EncryptWithKey:` message to obtain the ciphertext, which you should probably write out to a separate file. I'll refer you back to the NSString documentation for the path-manipulation methods you'll need to compute the output file path, and the NSData documentation for the method you'll need to write the ciphertext data out to the output file.

Comment: Thanks so much for this help. But say I only wanted to encrypt text-only files. So the snippet above did just that, right? If I were to use that snippet, how would I connect it to a button that extracts the contents of the file a user selects through that file selector to encrypt? Thanks again

Comment: @Husayn: Text files are a subset of all files, and the solution I gave works for all files. To restrict yourself to text files, tell the open panel that only text files should be enabled. The type you want to restrict to is `public.plain-text` (from http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html ). See the documentation for NSOpenPanel—and its superclass—for more details.

Comment: Ok got it. As you know I am a beginner when it comes to cocoa development. So how do I connect this encryption to the file a user selects through the selector?

Comment: @Husayn: “Selector” means something else here, which is explained in the Objective-C language document. The open panel gives you an array of filenames (or URLs—your choice), as shown in the code in your question. My answer explains what to do with those filenames (or URLs).

Comment: OH i see now, you help is greatly appreciated. I hope you don't mind if I ask you further questions if I get stuck.

Comment: @Husayn: If you need clarifications to my answer, you're welcome to ask for them in comments. If you need help with something else, you'll be better off asking another question.

Comment: Am I supposed to nest the NSData class in the for (NSString *path in [openPanel filenames]) {}?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by “nest the NSData class”.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. Am I supposed to put the snippet I provided in the "for (NSString *path in [openPanel filenames]) {...the snippet}? Also how can I connect an "encrypt" button to the actual encryption of the file?

Comment: Which snippet? Both snippets in your question are whole methods, and methods contain statements (a loop is a kind of statement), not the other way around. You need to replace the loop you have with the loop I suggested. As for hooking up the button, that's why your action method is an action. Hook up the button to the action in your nib. The Resources Programming Guide gives more information on nibs.

Comment: Sorry I mean the NSData method, of course not the file chooser

Comment: That won't work, for three reasons: Action methods don't return values; that doesn't write the output out to a file; and you only encrypt the input from one file, not all the opened files. It seems like you're behind on a lot of basic knowledge; I suggest reading Scott Stevenson's book (http://cocoabook.com/), at least for the first couple of chapters (essential C, and Objective-C), and all of the documentation I link to in this other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923049 Trust me, you can't skip this stuff. Learning it now will make everything go that much quicker.

Comment: Ok thanks for the references. Do you mind just telling me exactly how to resolve this problem though? I've been stuck on it for a while. I know I'm still a beginner.

Comment: And I actually do have decent familiarity with the iphone platform as I have programmed in that API consistently for the past few months but am new to cocoa.

Comment: I already did, in my answer. It tells you everything you need to do to solve your problem. Don't forget to follow the answer's documentation references, some of which I left purposefully vague as a (very easy!) exercise to your skill of looking things up in the docs.

Comment: What you're stuck on, though, is not any different in Cocoa from how it is in Cocoa Touch. The problem would be the same and the solution would be the same. If you already know how to solve it for an iOS app, then you already know how to solve it for a Mac app.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate all the help